# How to set path for Blazor app hosted in .NET Core

Tags: .net-core, hosting, blazor, fileprovider

I am trying to host a `Blazor` app via a `.NET Core Web Server`.I am using `FileProvider`.I do not know why i keep getting this error :

> blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: wasm streaming compile failed:
>   TypeError: Failed to execute 'compile' on 'WebAssembly': HTTP status
>   code is not ok WASM: falling back to ArrayBuffer instantiation Failed
>   to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not
>   Found) blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: both async and sync fetching of
>   the wasm failed blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: both async and sync
>   fetching of the wasm failed d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1
>   blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: failed to asynchronously prepare wasm:
>   abort("both async and sync fetching of the wasm failed"). Build with
>   -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info. d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1 blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: abort("both async and sync fetching of
>   the wasm failed"). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
>   blazor.webassembly.js:1 WASM: abort("both async and sync fetching of
>   the wasm failed"). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info.
>   d.printErr @ blazor.webassembly.js:1 localhost/:1 Uncaught (in
>   promise) abort("abort(\"both async and sync fetching of the wasm
>   failed\"). Build with -s ASSERTIONS=1 for more info."). Build with -s
>   ASSERTIONS=1 for more info. :5000/favicon.ico:1 Failed to load
>   resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

**.NET Core Host Startup**

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(@"D:/blazor/BenchUI/dist/");

            DefaultFilesOptions options = new DefaultFilesOptions
            {
                RequestPath = "",
                FileProvider = provider,
                DefaultFileNames = new List<string> { "index-browser.html" }
            };
            app.UseDefaultFiles(options);
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions()
            {
                RequestPath = "",
                FileProvider = provider,
            });
        }
    }
```

**Html root**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>BenchUI</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/site.css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>
    <app>Loading...</app>

    <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
    <script src="Utilities.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Folder structure**
I have set the root of my fileprovider as `dist` but there the `.NET Dll's` are outside that folder .Could my root be wrong ? I do not understand what is wrong since the only error appears to be in `blazor.webassembly.js`,a `script` which is added inside the `index.html`.

I do not understand where to run `dotnet [what dll name].dll`?Do i need to publish the `Client` project and the run `dotnet Client.dll` inside it or do i need to publish the `Client` `Server` and `Shared`.
So far i have tried with `dotnet [client name of dll].dll` and even `dotnet run (in the csproj location)

Comment: Have you tried `dotnet new blazorhosted` template?

Comment: I have tried using `dotnet run` on the `Client.dll` of the  project to no avail , so i made this host project for the `dist` folder and still does not work.

Comment: you can publish the host project and the publish output would work properly, and you dont have to create another one for the dist

Comment: I have used `dotnet publish -c Release [path to host project]` and i have used on that folder `dotnet Client.dll` and it does not work.

Comment: You need to `dotnet run` the dll in which the host project's `Main` class is.